# A newly-presented view controller immediately gets dismissed after appearing?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a view controller that calls another view controller with `present(newViewController...`. However, whenever the function that calls this present function is called, the new view controller pops up on the screen for a second before being dismissed again. There are no functions in this new view controller to dismiss itself.

The only thing I can think of that may be causing this is my use of SnapKit and overriding of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if let data = data {
            return
        } else { setupAVFoundation() }
    }
```

`data` is an optional value that is set by the time I present the new view controller, so `viewDidLayoutSubviews` returns at the `if let` statement. However I have confirmed that upon presenting the new view controller, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called like four times. I can't figure out why this is happening or why it would interrupt presentation of a new view controller.

Here is where the new view is presented:

```
    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
        data = code
        present(ItemSelectViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```